# How to extend a set of points in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, data-fitting

Suppose I have the landmark points on a face, as follows :

[image]

and I want to calculate (estimate) the upper boundaries from them, by selecting the outer chin landmarks and extending them, so I want to achieve new points like this : 
[image]

So I want to "follow" the curve that is generated by points 1,2 and 3, and put equi-distant points on top, so that I can crop the image using the `boundary` function of MATLAB.

I guess I need to fit a 2nd order polynomial to the data points, but I'm not sure how. So how can I generate these points?

Thanks for any help,

### Edit

Here are the coordinates of an example landmark set:

image:
[image]

Landmarks (1:3 , i.e. left) :

```
   x         y  
431.1901  547.9975
438.7422  611.0103
451.4842  668.0488
```

Landmarks (17:-1:15 , i.e. right)

```
   x         y  
876.6581  509.5234
878.1327  568.9854
880.7731  619.5879
```

### Edit 2

Here is a complete set of coordinates of the 17 chin landmarks:

```
   1.0e+03 *

    1.1974    1.3956
    1.2266    1.5488
    1.2554    1.6876
    1.2766    1.8245
    1.3266    1.9530
    1.4098    2.0648
    1.5420    2.1567
    1.6719    2.2222
    1.8180    2.2444
    1.9585    2.1991
    2.0642    2.1208
    2.1761    2.0351
    2.2575    1.9243
    2.3038    1.7937
    2.3191    1.6580
    2.3376    1.5264
    2.3537    1.3825
```

Comment: You could fit an ellipse to the outer boundary?

Comment: @lhcgeneva Thanks, but how do I do that?

Comment: Can you provide the set of green points for the chin landmark?

Comment: @lhcgeneva done. But I would really appreciate a code example, preferrably in MATLAB.

Comment: Maybe landmarks wasn't the right thing to ask for, I meant the 17 points you've got.

Comment: The coordinates for all the 17 points? Ok, I'm adding them, but they are for another image. Indexing is the same though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fit_ellipse()` from [File Exchange](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3215-fit-ellipse) created by Ohad Gal.

You need to slightly modify it, so it also returns the plot handle which you are going to use to extract the data. For this, change the header to

```
function [ellipse_t, h] = fit_ellipse( x,y,axis_handle )
```

and add

```
     h = gca;

to the bottom of the file.
```

Then do

```
close all;
clear all;
landmarks = [1.1974    1.3956; 1.2266    1.5488; 1.2554    1.6876;
             1.2766    1.8245; 1.3266    1.9530; 1.4098    2.0648
             1.5420    2.1567; 1.6719    2.2222; 1.8180    2.2444
             1.9585    2.1991; 2.0642    2.1208; 2.1761    2.0351
             2.2575    1.9243; 2.3038    1.7937; 2.3191    1.6580
             2.3376    1.5264; 2.3537    1.3825];

[e, h] = fit_ellipse(landmarks(:, 1), landmarks(:, 2), gcf);
ch=get(h,'Children');
x=get(ch,'Xdata');
y=get(ch,'Ydata');
plot(x,y);
hold on;
x_l = landmarks(:, 1);
y_l = landmarks(:, 2);
plot(x_l, y_l);
m = min(landmarks(:, 2)); %Get the smallest y value from your landmarks
y_subset = y(y<m);
x_subset = x(y<m);
plot(x_subset, y_subset, 'r.', 'MarkerSize', 10)
axis equal;
```

which produces

[image]

Here, red points are your new sample points. Also note, that in your case obviously the y axis is inverted, because you are displaying an image. This does not change anything in the code though.

**Alternatively, if speed is important:** Comment out the draw section at the very bottom of fit_ellipse(). Change the function header to

```
function [ellipse_t, rotated_ellipse] = fit_ellipse( x,y )
```

and use the following code:

```
[e, r] = fit_ellipse(landmarks(:, 1), landmarks(:, 2));
x = r(1, :);
y = r(2, :);
x_l = landmarks(:, 1);
y_l = landmarks(:, 2);
m = min(landmarks(:, 2)); %Get the smallest y value from your landmarks
y_subset = y(y<m);
x_subset = x(y<m);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And how do I generate the new points (the red ones in the second image) ?

Comment: Just take a subset of x and y?

Comment: I already know x and y? How will taking a subset of them help? I really don't understand how do we complete this ellipse, and sample the points that are on the "top" part of it?

Comment: ah, you are using points from the plot. it's brilliantly simple, thanks :) and sorry for not understanding earlier.. but i want to analytically compute the points, and plot them only if i want to, since plotting by default might make it slower, right?